# How to revoke a GPG key without confirmation?

Tags: command-line, scripting, gpg

After running the following command to revoke a key

```
gpg --gen-revoke <key ID>
```

I have to then press <kbd>y</kbd>, 2 times <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>y</kbd>

**How would you suggest to answer automatically, that is revoking a key without any other user interaction than the passphrase prompt?**

Comment: Except: `gpg --batch --gen-revoke testing` --> `gpg: can't do this in batch mode`

Comment: with [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that gpg [opens the controlling terminal directly](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=util/ttyio.c;h=97b160ef2b2d9f124dbb6fc2e11af46f7b39d980;hb=b12d50dccd0a1d54cad10bde3ed6bd94070518c9#l86), so you're unable to redirect input.